# Traverse a javascript object recursively and replace a value by key

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, recursion

Since JSON can not perfom functions i need to eval a JSON string by a key flag in the JSON object. I want to mutate the JSON data when it's in Object form.

I can't find a function/method online that can give me the full path to key based on a known key pattern.

Given this data:

```
  {
    "js:bindto": "#chart-1", // note the key here 'js:'
    "point": {
        "r": 5
    },
    "data": {
        "x": "x",
        "xFormat": "%Y",
        "columns": [
            ...
        ],
        "colors": {
            "company": "#ed1b34",
            "trendline": "#ffffff"
        }
    },
    "legend": {
        "show": false
    },
    "axis": {
        "x": {
            "padding": {
                "left": 0
            },
            "type": "timeseries",
            "tick": {
                "format": "%Y",
                "outer": false
            }
        },
        "y": {
            "tick": {
                "outer": false,
                "js:format": "d3.format(\"$\")" // note the key here 'js:'
            }
        }
    },
    "grid": {
        "lines": {
            "front": false
        },
        "y": {
            "lines": [...]
        }
    }
}
```

The flags are keys beginning with `js:`.

If I look up `js:format`, I'd expect it's path to be something like: `/js:bindto` and `/axis/y/tick/js:format`. Open to suggestions.

In context:

```
mutateGraphData<T>(data:T):T {
   // data here is a parsed JSON string. ( an object as shown above )

    let jsonKeys = this.findKeysInJSON(JSON.stringify(data), "js:");

    // jsonKeys = ["js:bindto","js:format"]
        jsonKeys.map((key:string) => {
          // find the key in data, then modify the value. (stuck here)
         // i need the full path to the key so i can change the data property that has the key in question
        });
    });
    return data;
}

findKeysInJSON<T>(jsonString:string, key:string):Array<T> {
        let keys = [];
        if (Boolean(~(jsonString.indexOf(`"${key}`)))) {
            let regEx = new RegExp(key + "(\\w|\\-)+", "g");
            keys = jsonString.match(regEx);
        }
        return keys;
}
```

I have been around a few npm packages:

- [object search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-search) no wild card lookaround
- [dotty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotty) looks good, but fails with search: "*.js:format"
- https://github.com/capaj/object-resolve-path - needs full path to key. I don't know that in advance.

I have looked at

- [JavaScript recursive search in JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222599/javascript-recursive-search-in-json-object)
- [Find property by name in a deep object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642494/find-property-by-name-in-a-deep-object)
- DefiantJS ( no npm module )
- https://gist.github.com/iwek/3924925

Nothing have I seen can return the full path to the key in question so I can modify it, nor work directly on the object itself so I can change its properties.

Comment: what is `mutateGraphData<T>(data:T):T` for a language?

Comment: @NinaScholz: TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com). It has built in functions that will allow you to map over an object and modify parts of the object in a completely immutable way.

Ramda offers `R.lensPath` that will allow you to dig into the object, and modify it as needed. It doesn't follow the pattern you want, but we can quickly patch it with the `lensify` function.

It is using the `R.set` function to set the node to the passed in value, and creating a pipeline that will run all the operations on the passed in object.

You can do some really cool stuff with ramda and lenses. Checkout evilsoft on livecoding.tv for a really good overview.

```js
const obj={"js:bindto":"#chart-1",point:{r:5},data:{x:"x",xFormat:"%Y",columns:[],colors:{company:"#ed1b34",trendline:"#ffffff"}},legend:{show:!1},axis:{x:{padding:{left:0},type:"timeseries",tick:{format:"%Y",outer:!1}},y:{tick:{outer:!1,"js:format":'d3.format("$")'}}},grid:{lines:{front:!1},y:{lines:[]}}}

const lensify = path => R.lensPath(path.split('/'))
// create the property accessors split by /
const bindToLens = lensify('js:bindto')
const formatLens = lensify('axis/y/tick/js:format')

const modifyObj = R.pipe(
  R.set(bindToLens, 'dis be bind'),
  R.set(formatLens, 'I been here')
)

console.log(modifyObj(obj))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @georg watch https://www.livecoding.tv/evilsoft/videos/d5BDO-functional-js-lenses it will take a couple of hours to sink in, but well worth the effort

Comment: Useful. But still on line 6, I'd need to know the full path in order to mutate that property.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a look around I modified the answer from [Javascript/JSON get path to given subnode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790607/javascript-json-get-path-to-given-subnode) @adam-rackis

```
function search(obj, target, path = "") {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
            if (k === target)
                return path + "." + k;
            else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
                var result = search( obj[k], target, path + "." + k );
                if (result){
                     return result;
                }
            }
    }
    return false;
}

search(data,"js:format").slice(1); // returns: axis.y.tick.js:format
search(data,"js:bindto").slice(1); // returns: js:bindto
```

Now I can use `dotty` or `object-resolve-path` or plain ole `split('.')` to resolve the path to the object.

Answer (score 0):

With [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#readme) this should be a one liner. We've been using it a lot for data processing and it's powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you could use it

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (data) => objectScan(['**.js:*'], { joined: true })(data);

const data = { 'js:bindto': '#chart-1', point: { r: 5 }, data: { x: 'x', xFormat: '%Y', columns: [], colors: { company: '#ed1b34', trendline: '#ffffff' } }, legend: { show: false }, axis: { x: { padding: { left: 0 }, type: 'timeseries', tick: { format: '%Y', outer: false } }, y: { tick: { outer: false, 'js:format': 'd3.format("$")' } } }, grid: { lines: { front: false }, y: { lines: [] } } };

console.log(find(data));
// => [ 'axis.y.tick.js:format', 'js:bindto' ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)